# HTML Doctype very first thing?

Tags: html, doctype

Is it valid to have blank line returns preceding the doctype declaration?

> The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration must be the very first thing in your HTML
>   document, before the `<html>` tag.

via [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Comment: [obligatory w3fools reference](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @zzzzBov Never seen this before, don't know if I fully agree with it. Any source for knowledge and learning is beneficial. Thanks for sharing though, I didn't even know the argument existed.

Comment: "Any source for knowledge and learning is beneficial" learning incorrect information isn't learning. I find w3schools to be wholly unreliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily; BOM, whitespace and comments may come first.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/documents.html#syntax-document-html

So yeah, it must come first, before any actual HTML tags, but note that you can't really ever put doctype before BOM.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had no clue what a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) was until now.